# Incorrect output using forms

Tags: powershell

Command line `$X = 3927,3988,4073,4151` looks great,

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $X
3927
3988
4073
4151
```

but if I have it read from a form it echoes
`3927,3988,4073,4151`

Should I be using something other than `$XBox.Text`?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$Title = "Numeric ID"
$Form = New-Object "System.Windows.Forms.Form"
$Form.Width = 850
$Form.Height = 140
$Form.Text = $Title
$Form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

$XLabel = New-Object "System.Windows.Forms.Label";$XLabel.Left = 5;$XLabel.Top = 18;$XLabel.Text = 'My Numbers:'
$XBox = New-Object "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox";$XBox.Left = 105;$XBox.Top = 15;$XBox.width = 700
$DefaultValue = ""
$XBox.Text = $DefaultValue
$Button = New-Object "System.Windows.Forms.Button";$Button.Left = 400;$Button.Top = 45;$Button.Width = 100;$Button.Text = "Accept"
$EventHandler = [System.EventHandler]{
    $XBox.Text
    $Form.Close()
}
$Button.Add_Click($EventHandler)
$Form.Controls.Add($button)
$Form.Controls.Add($XLabel)
$Form.Controls.Add($XBox)
$Ret = $Form.ShowDialog()
$X = @($XBox.Text)
```

Answer (score 3):

- **`$X` contains an *array* of *numbers*** - number literals that are parsed into `[int]` instances, assembled into an `[object[]]` array via `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-).

  ```bash
  PS> $X = 3927,3988,4073,4151; $X.GetType().FullName; $X[0].GetType().FullName
  System.Object[]  # Type of the array; [object[]], in PowerShell terms.
  System.Int32     # Type of the 1st element; [int], in PowerShell terms.
  ```
- By contrast, **`$XBox.Text` contains a *single string*** that only happens to *look like* the source code that defined `$X` array.

If you want to interpret this string *as PowerShell source code* in order to get an array of numbers, you *could* use `Invoke-Expression`, but that is generally [ill-advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375) for security reasons.

A safer way is to perform a constrained interpretation of the string yourself (this would work even with incidental whitespace around the numbers):

```bash
[int[]] ('3927,3988,4073,4151' -split ',')
```

Output (an array of `[int]` values):

```
3927
3988
4073
4151
```